# Could not resolve placeholder 'envVerNum' in value "${envVerNum}" in Application Properties in sts4

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, environment-variables, sts

In MacOS, they just open terminal and do these

```
vi .bash_profile
```

here vi is something like text editor ..

then the file named .bash_profile popsup and they store

```
export envVerNum=2.2.2
```

and save it and close it.

then open terminal again and type

```
echo $envVerNum
```

it returns 2.2.2 !
it also returns in sts4 !

Now, Whats the process in Windows ! Please explain me as i am noob to this Spring Boot !

I tried setting environment varibles directly on control panel ! that doesnt work.. tell me something "it need some configuration"
and
I tried setting environment variables insde the sts4 run and debug settings.

I expect that ... i want to store envVerNum=2.2.2 outside the sts4 and call it on Application Properties.

please explain me !

Comment: Java properties and environment variables are different things. To set the Java property, start your Java application with the VM argument `-DenvVerNum=2.2.2`. In Java you can get the value of an environment variable via `System.getenv("envVerNum")`. Please show your code where and how you access `envVerNum` and tell why you do what (and whether you want to use a Java property or an environment variable for it).

Answer (score 0):

using CMD (not powershell) execute SET command to see all environmental variables including all that you set up through contro-lpanel.

Microsoft Docs has extensive documentation on all aspects of environmental variables (RTFM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1)

The problem, IMHO ,you are not aware of difference between "environmental variable" on different OS platform (*nix, windows,   Mac)